# Использование String в цикле

Tags: java, строки

Наткнулся на информацию, что при  конкатенации строк на Java с помощью оператора +, например, в цикле for, каждый раз создается новый объект String, что приводит к потере памяти и увеличению времени работы программы.

Так ли это? И чем заменить сложение строк в цикле?
Stringbilder грузит конкретно и точно приводит к повышенному расходу памяти

Answer (score 2):

Заменить сложение строк чем-то более быстрым чем `StringBuilder` практически нечем, так как `StringJoiner`, `String::join`, и др. под капотом используют его, впрочем как и сам оператор `+`, о чём [указано в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html):

> The implementation of the string concatenation operator is left to the discretion of a Java compiler, as long as the compiler ultimately conforms to The Java™ Language Specification. For example, the javac compiler may implement the operator with `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`, or `java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory` depending on the JDK version.

> Вольный перевод
> Реализация оператора конкатенации строк оставляется на усмотрение Java компилятора, поскольку в конечном итоге компилятор соответствует спецификации языка Java JLS.  Например, javac компилятор может реализовать этот оператор, используя `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`, или `java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory` в зависимости от версии JDK.

Также `StringBuilder` быстрее потокобезопасного `StringBuffer` за счёт отсутствия синхронизации, о чём также [указано в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), и поэтому именно он рекомендуется в однопоточном коде:

> This class provides an API compatible with `StringBuffer`, but with no guarantee of synchronization. This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for `StringBuffer` in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is generally the case). Where possible, **it is recommended that this class be used in preference to `StringBuffer` as it will be faster under most implementations**.

Для увеличения производительности `StringBuilder` при работе с большими строками, может понадобиться установить его объём capacity при создании экземпляра:

```java
StringBuilder large = new StringBuilder(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // максимальный размер
```

Answer (score 1):

Эксперимент String += против StringBuilder.

```
public class ConcatenationString {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            s += " ";
        }
        System.out.println(s.length());
    }
}

public class ConcatenationStringBuilder {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        String s = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(s.length());
    }
}
```

Сравниваем для тысячи символов:

> ```
> $ javac -version
> javac 1.8.0_45
>
> $ javac ConcatenationString.java ConcatenationStringBuilder.java 
>
> $ time java ConcatenationString 1000
> 1000
>
> real  0m0.055s
> user  0m0.052s
> sys   0m0.004s
>
> $ time java ConcatenationStringBuilder 1000
> 1000
>
> real  0m0.055s
> user  0m0.044s
> sys   0m0.008s
> ```

Время равное, но это пока. Таблица:

> ```
>          n         String   StringBuilder
>
>          1         0.050с         0.048с
>         10         0.053с         0.051с
>        100         0.062с         0.050с
>       1000         0.054с         0.051с
>      10000         0.138с         0.062с
>     100000         4.768с         0.055с
>    1000000       177.833с         0.067с
>   10000000                        0.188с
>  100000000                        0.978с
> 1000000000                        9.284с
> ```

0.05с - это время старта Java, так что маленькие размеры не сравнишь просто так. Рост для `String` очень быстрый. Рост для `StringBuilder` медленный, в конце время работы пропорционально конечному размеру строки. На что тратится время? На выделение памяти, копирование пробелов, освобождение памяти и так без конца.

Что можно сказать точно:

- Надо мерять время. Без чисел - всё болтовня.
- На больших размерах (от 10000 символов) только StringBuilder.
- На маленьких размерах - не понятно. Надо мерять время более тонко, тут померяно очень грубо.
- Надо понимать что под капотом. Исходный код стандартной библиотеки есть, можно заглянуть.
- Надо знать что такое О-большое. Очень сокращает время спора по некоторым вопросам. Этот ответ написан без отсылок к О-большому, потому так длинно.